# Resposive site, zoom in mobile site

Tags: css, responsive-design

Im working on responsive site. I have adapted this site for different resolutions(from fullhd reolution to 320x480), but when I enter this site fom my 4.3" mobile it loads a site with 1200px width, and when i make zoom - a horizontal scrollbar  appears, but I want a browser to resize window.
What directive must I add for browser for that?

Comment: are you using `@media-queries`?

Answer (score 2):

From what you say it sounds like you haven't got the necessary meta line in your head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

which makes mobiles cooperate with your media queries (assuming you have them? - you haven't answered Fahad's question above yet). It would help if you show your CSS for this.